# im installing mahento 2.4 using xamp on windows everything goes well but a connection error with elastic search

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

[Progress: 671 / 1346]
Installing search configuration...

In SearchConfig.php line 81:

Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. null

this is my installation command:

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/magento24/" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento2" --db-user="root" --db-password="moohariosCK1!" --admin-firstname="Mohammad" --admin-lastname="Ibrahim" --admin-email="mail@mail.com" --admin-user="elastic" --admin-password="*****" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin" --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host="es1:9200" --elasticsearch-port=9200
```

Comment: In your system is Elasticsearch is installed if yes then check it is active or not.

Comment: its active on localhost:9200

Comment: cluster_name "elasticsearch"
cluster_uuid "DmZlrvetQ9yvcRYf0iSgoA"
version 
number "8.2.0"
build_flavor "default"
build_type "zip"
build_hash "b174af62e8dd9f4ac4d25875e9381ffe2b9282c5"
build_date "2022-04-20T10:35:10.180408517Z"
build_snapshot false
lucene_version "9.1.0"
minimum_wire_compatibility_version "7.17.0"
minimum_index_compatibility_version "7.0.0"
tagline "You Know, for Search"

Comment: Can you run this command : sudo service elasticsearch status and check if it is running or not.

Comment: im on windows mate

Comment: Oh sorry check the status for windows then maybe it will help https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/323337#:~:text=1.,smarts%2Fbin%2Fsm_service%20show.&text=2.,tool%20like%20curl%20on%20Linux.
if not working then restart the Elasticsearch service and if still not working then post the error which you have got.

Comment: error 
root_cause 
0 
type "index_not_found_exception"
reason "no such index [status]"
resource.type "index_or_alias"
resource.id "status"
index_uuid "_na_"
index "status"
type "index_not_found_exception"
reason "no such index [status]"
resource.type "index_or_alias"
resource.id "status"
index_uuid "_na_"
index "status"
status 404

Comment: you can try using external elasticsearch to test the connection first, try bonsai.io they provide free trial

Comment: its working, just for some reason it woudnt connect to magento 2